# Check for items inside a Entity Framework linq result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to check to see if any results were returned from an entity framework query before acting upon it, I'm trying to use the code :-

```
var shoppingCartSessions = from c in context.ShoppingCartSessions where c.UserId == gUserID select c;
if (shoppingCartSessions.First() != null)
{
}
```

However I get the error

> Sequence contains no elements

I have checked around stack and found that I can replace `.First` with `.FirstOrDefault` however I wanted to check if this is the correct way to be checking for existence of elements. Is there a better way rather than trying to fetch the item and then checking it?

Comment: If any of the options below answered your question feel free to accept it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
var shoppingCartSessions = from c in context.ShoppingCartSessions 
                           where c.UserId == gUserID 
                           select c;
if (shoppingCartSessions.Any())
{
     //not empty
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried checking `.Count() > 0` ?

**EDIT:**
As stated by Mahmoud Gamal, using `Any()` should render slightly better performance, since it will execute an EXISTS query, rather than a COUNT() on the DB, and you ultimately don't care about the exact amount.

Comment: I think I'm going blind, I didn't even see that function! I was checking for .Length and .Size heh.

Comment: Don't use .Count(). It will perform an iteration through all items (and since you're using EF, materialize them in the process). Use Any() instead.

Comment: If you're working against `IQueryable<>` it should not materialize anything but request a Count to the back-end database. Have you checked the actual query generated by EF?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I still think `Any()` is in fact a better answer, since you don't actually care about the number of results and a SQL EXISTS statement would suffice, but I doubt EF would actually materialize anything in that scenario.